# VSCode restore file from tmp file

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, temporary-files, tmp, tsx

I Accidentally discarded some changed files in VScode and lost alot of work. I believe I have found them saved as tmp files in the

/users/appdata/local/temp/1 directory, but when I try to open it's just symbols/binary encoding that I am not familar with. These were typescript files with the extension .tsx...when I open with VScode or notepad I just see the wierd symbols which I believe are  binary encoding.

Is there a way to restore the temp file to  a text or typescript file???

Comment: do you have SCM or backups, then your only hope is using an SSD drive and a recovery program

Comment: @rioV8 I dont unfortunately. Is there no way to get the plain text that exists from the tmp file??

Comment: most likely that is the undo history, you can't get the file back from such a file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now and I just renamed the file, changing the extension from ".tmp" to ".cs" and it worked, I lost a few lines of code but it was fine.

I don't know if this will work for every case though.